# Grails: how to retrieve a persistent value for the collection?

Tags: grails, collections, persistence, beforeupdate

I'm writing a Grails application and I need to retrieve a persistent value for the collection of my domain class objects. Let's consider we have got the following domain object:

```
class UserGroup {
   SortedSet<User> users
   static hasMany = [ users: User ]
   // ...
   def beforeUpdate() {
      println "BEFORE UPDATE: " + this.getPersistentValue('users');
   }
}

class User implements Comparable<User> {
   String name
}
```

And the controller which has the following action:

```
class UserGroupController {
   def addUser() {
      UserGroup group = UserGroup.get(params.long('gid'))
      User user = User.get(params.long('uid'))

      group.addToUsers(user)
      group.save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
   }
}
```

The problem is that when `beforeUpdate()` is called, the users collection already contains the recently added user. So, seems that `addTo()` method doesn't trigger the `beforeUpdate()` event.

The same problem occurs when we're talking about `isDirty()` method. As the changes are applied before the `beforeUpdate()` is called, the collection is not recognized as dirty field.

Does anyone know how to change this? I'm writing a feature which tracks the history of changes for lots of different object, so I need to have access to the previous value in order to understand whether its value was changed or not.

Comment: Grails has a stack trace which might be useful in this situation, under conf DataSource.groovy you can set: logSql = true to see when the changes are being applied.

Comment: Thanks, i'm already using this feature for debug purposes!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue, where things are being updated when I wasn't expecting them when I used the **.get()** on domain classes. I like to use **.read()** now because it wont update the database when I'm not expecting it to. Grails does a lot of sneaky things behind the sense which are helpful I think but can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks, this can be helpful in case when you need to avoid unnecessary updates, which are done by Gorm. But this doesn't answer the question, how to get a persistent value for the collection, that was already changed by calling addTo() method but not flushed to the DB yet.